# Unexpected behavior while updating instance variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm facing issue in updating one of the instance variable. Below is the code snippet:

```
class DataFormatting:

    def __init__(self):
        self.default_dict = dict()
        # default values
        self.default_model = {'message': 'Please try after some time'}
        self.default_dict['statusCode'] = 500
        self.default_dict['body'] = {'type': 'lead',
                                                'status': self.default_dict['statusCode'],
                                                'model': self.default_model}

        self.default_dict['headers'] = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    def get_response(self):
        return self.default_dict

    def set_response(self, status_code, final_response):
        self.default_dict['statusCode'] = status_code
        self.default_dict['body']['model'] = final_response

ob = DataFormatting()
ob.set_response(200, {'key1': 'value1'})
ob.get_response()
```

Output:

```
{'statusCode': 200,
 'body': {'type': 'lead', 'status': 500, 'model': {'key1': 'value1'}},
 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
```

Although the key "statusCode" getting updated as 200, "status" inside "body" is still 500. How should I resolve this?

Comment: How can you expect ```self.default_dict['body']['status']``` to anonymously become ```200``` without you actually doing that? You are missing that statement to do so.

Comment: @JenilDave: Since I'm a newbie to oops, I thought that updating self.default_dict['statusCode'] = status_code will automatically update self.default_dict['body']['status] because of -->  'status': self.default_dict['statusCode']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status within the body is configured at the creation of the object. To update it when calling '`set_response`', you need to include a command for updating `body.status` as well

```
 def set_response(self, status_code, final_response):
        self.default_dict['statusCode'] = status_code
        self.default_dict['body']['model'] = final_response

        self.default_dict['body']['status'] = status_code
```

The above code change in set_response should be able to fix it. But, you should ideally create an 'update_status' method that takes care of status updates across the object

Comment: I suggest that instead of having the same data item replicated in different places across the object and then using a setter function to make consistent copies, it may usually be preferable to have it stored in once place only, and then move to the getter function (in this case `get_response`) the task of making any additional copies required by calling code.

Comment: Yes. That'd be a better practice. Have status in one place, and get other methods to refer to it. Make copies when needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataFormatting` object has two data items that are clearly intended to have the same contents as each other, but are stored independently:

`self.default_dict['statusCode']`

and

`self.default_dict['body']['status']`

They are set to the same as each other in `__init__`, but are then allowed to diverge from each other in `set_response` at the point where one is updated but not the other.

I suggest that your data model is wrong, and each value should be stored in one place, and one place **only**.  For example, you could store it at `self.default_dict['body']['status']`.  If a response then needs to contain a copy of the status at `response['statusCode']` and this is not where your object stores it internally, then you could change the `get_response` method so that instead of simply returning `self.default_dict`, it makes a copy of it (or possibly a deep copy using `copy.deepcopy`) and then sets the `'statusCode'` item within the copy before returning the copy.

Comment: I'd prefer this over my answer, as it is a more robust practice.